# Pandas read data from a secure FTP server in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ftp

I am looking for a neat solution to read data (using either read_csv or read_sas) to a Pandas Dataframe from a secure FTP server in Python 3. All the examples I can find are many lines and some for Python 2. Isn't there a neat way to insert your username+password to Pandas read_csv-like method together with an ftp url and folder?

Comment: Notably, for security reasons I want to read the data straight to my Python memory from the ftp server file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv()` accepts a file-like object.  Paramiko is a library which handles SFTP and can provide file-like objects. Once you've [set up the connection](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_sftp.py), it's simple as:

```
with sftp.open("file.csv") as f:
    pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: This assumes UTF-8 encoding, do you have a solution that handles other encodings?